# How to click on the button with text as Close within a modal dialog box as per the html through Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver using C#, but selenium isn't identifying my Modal Window.

I have tried:

```
 IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
 alert.Accept();
```

But it doesn't work. In the code the modal has 'ID' but, it doesn't work either.

[image: Code]

I need identify the modal and click in the button.

Comment: Hi. If you include your code in your question as text, users can copy/paste it to try it and so give you help much more readily.

Comment: Are you sure that the modal is visible to you try to switch to it? Have you tried checking first to see if the element is visible?

Comment: Thanks for the tip :D Really, my modal isn´t visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to click on the button with text as **Close** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("button.close[data-dismiss='modal'][aria-label='Close']"))).Click();
  ```
- Using `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//button[@class='close' and @data-dismiss='modal'][@aria-label='Close']"))).Click();
  ```